# Environment for reading files within R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, do.call

I'm creating a simple GUI in Shiny for reading in a bunch of csv files and then filtering them by values present in the 5th column of each csv.  I'm not sure how to access the correct shiny environment however.  For example, within the server function, I first read the files in with the lines:

```
for (i in all_paths) {
    
        n <- basename(i)
        temp = list.files(path = i, pattern="*.csv",full.names = TRUE)
        list2env(
          lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub(".*FRSTseg*", n, temp))), 
                 read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
      }
```

And then filter with:

```
Pattern1<-grep("*.csv",names(.GlobalEnv),value=TRUE)
    all_data<-do.call("list",mget(Pattern1))
    
    newdfs <- lapply(all_data, function(x) subset(x, x[, 5] > 0))
    
    list2env(newdfs,globalenv())
```

When I run the app, I get en error message saying it can't find the value of one of my csvs, which I have found to be the first element of the `Pattern1` list.  So I'm pretty sure the app fails right after the `Pattern1` line.

I think the problem is that the csv files are not being read into the correct environment, such that the `all_data <- do.call...` line does not know where to look.  So instead of using .GlobalEnv and globalenv, what should I be using?  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your earlier code properly reading the csv files in the first place? If the csv files aren't in the same working directory as the app, you can run into issues.

Comment: Yes, after I get the error message, and then close the app, I see all the files in the global environment window of the Rstudio interface.

Comment: `list2env(newdfs,globalenv())` is *extremely* questionable. Why not keep working with the list `newdfs`? — Except for very rare exceptions, you shouldn’t muck with environments. Consider them immutable and static.

Comment: @beanboy I think you mean the read-in objects? You shouldn't see *files* in the global environment.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reactiveValues` and store the result of `read_csv` to be available across all observers in the app. I created a small app that reads the 5th column of different .csv files located in the project directory. In this case all the data will be stored inside an object called `column_read$files` that can be invoked inside any observer or reactive.

app:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
set.seed(15)

#create the data
paste0('iris', 1:5, '.csv') %>% 
    map(~write_csv(x = slice_sample(iris,n = 10), .x))

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('read_files', "Read Files"),
    textOutput('columns_print')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    columns_read <- reactiveValues(files = NULL)
    
    
    observeEvent(input$read_files, {
        files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv",full.names = TRUE)
        
        columns_read$files <- map(files, ~read_csv(.x, col_select = 5))
    })
    
    output$columns_print <- renderPrint({
        req(columns_read$files)
        columns_read$files
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```